# First element of the DropdownList not getting selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down box which is being populated by enteries from database. But the first value in the DropDownList is not working. Please help me out

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Models.Bookinfo>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "NewRequest";
 }

<h2>NewRequest</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Reserve","Book" ))
{
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Bookname",Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() 
                              {Text = m.Bookname, Value = m.Bookname }).ToList())
         </td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
         <td> 
            <input type = submit value="Reserve">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
}
```

Actualy it is giving null value. Can i do like this put some random text as the first element of the list like "select a book " and start the list from second element

Now I am facing another problem. it is not able to reserve any newly created book. and i can't seem to figure out the problem

```
 public ActionResult Reserve(string bookname,Issued issue)
    {
        try 
            {
        using (var db = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            var bookID= (from some in db.Bookinfoes where some.Bookname==bookname select some.Id).First();
          //  var issueddate = (from issuedate in db.Issueds where issuedate.BookId == bookID select issuedate.date).First();
                if (db.Issueds.Where(i=>i.BookId == bookID).FirstOrDefault().BookId != 0 )
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("AlreadyReserved");
                }

            var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
            issue.BookId = bookID;
            issue.date = date;
            db.Issueds.Add(issue);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }    
        }
            catch
            {
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        return View();
    }
```

It is always catching an exception and returning to the index page

Comment: isn't there anything like BookId in your view model?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "The first value is not working"? The title of your question suggests that it isn't selected by default. Or do you mean that you cannot select the first value?

Comment: by that i mean whenever i select a bookname from the list it should allow me to reserve that book or show that it is already reserved. But that is not happening with the first element of the list. It is taking me back to the list page which I have given in exception

Comment: actually i think it is giving null value

Comment: Perhaps your first book has "null" as name? You should check your data in this case. And follow +Neel's suggestion of using the book-ids instead of the name.

Comment: it does not have a null name. and what do i get out of id's? I tried adding id instead of bookname but then nothing is getting selected

Comment: Please post the generated HTML code from the browser (just the part with the dropdown, i.e. the `<select>` and the `<option>` tags. perhaps we can see, if there is a problem...

Comment: actually i got it. it was due to a null value from the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give BookId as the value as shown below :-

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Bookname",Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() 
                              {Text = m.Bookname, Value = m.BookId}).ToList())
```

Comment: by doing that nothing is getting selected

Comment: means it is catching an exception and returning back to index page. coz the value is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Selected` Propertys of the first `SelectListItem` to true. Since you're already using a LINQ-Expression to build up the list, you could use something like (the second parameter in the lambda expression passed to `Select` receives the index of the element...):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Bookname", Model.Select((m,i) => new SelectListItem
                   {Text = m.Bookname, Value=m.Bookname, Selected = i==0}).ToList())
```

**Edit**: If you want to have some arbitrary text as your first item (like "Select a book"), you can achieve that by adding an additional `SelectListItem` in front of your books. This can be done using some "LINQ magic" like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Bookname", 
    Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem {Text = "Select a book", Value=null, Selected=True}, 1)
    .Concat(Model.Select((m,i) => new SelectListItem
      {Text = m.Bookname, Value=m.Bookname}))
    .ToList())
```

Note: `Enumerable.Repeat` is used to create a sequence containing exactly one element. Also in this case, you can set the `Selected` property of the first element to `True` and leave it `False` on the rest of the list.

Comment: That ist strange. What do you mean by 'is not working'? The first element doesn't get selected? Could you perhaps post the generated HTML (i.e. the "Source" from your browser...)?

Comment: actually the first element is coming as null

Comment: Can i do like this put some random text as the first element of the list like "select a book " and start the list from second element

Comment: If the first element is null, perhaps you have a "null book" (i.e. a Book without name) in your data? (In which case you might review your downvote, since the answer is not "useless" imo?)

Comment: i don't have a book without a name